# Difficult pushing existing django application to Heroku. Database improperly configured

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

So I have a finished Django application and I am now trying to upload it to Heroku to go to production although I am running into some problems. I have been following the tutorials on Heroku's site:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#migrating-an-existing-django-project

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#declare-process-types-with-procfile

Although I am running into this error:

```
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

It sounded like I needed to upload my database onto S3 so Heroku could access it so I did that with this tutorial

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import

but I am still getting the error. Here are some of my settings.

**Settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'texchange',
        'USER': 'joe',
        'PASSWORD': '#######',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('/static/',
    '/home/joe/Documents/exchange/Texchange/textchange/static/',),
    ('/media/',
    '/home/joe/Documents/exchange/Texchange/textchange/media/'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/joe/Documents/exchange/Texchange/textchange/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/joe/Documents/exchange/Texchange/textchange/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

# Enable Persistent Connections
DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 500
```

What exactly am I not understanding? Any direction would be appreciated as this is my first time uploading an application with Heroku and S3.

Comment: Post your `DATABASE_URL` that you set in the Heroku admin

Comment: Right now it's the default that it starts with. I tried setting it to the dump file i uploaded to S3 but I get the error: DATABASE_URL is invalid. Must be in the format FOO=bar.

Comment: It seems likely that Heroku is not finding your settings, since you obviously have configured the engine in the code you have posted. Can you show your Procfile, and the file layout showing where settings.py is?

Comment: This is all I have in my Procfile: web: gunicorn exchange.wsgi --log-file -

Comment: It's only when I run "Heroku local" that I get the database error.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in the comments that this problem only happens when you run `heroku local`, which is a *completely different problem* and certainly an issue you should have mentioned at the start in your question. Clearly, this isn't about "uploading your application to Heroku", or even about Heroku not finding the db, since you are not even running on Heroku yet but locally.

The problem almost certainly occurs because in your local environment you don't have a DATABASE_URL, yet you have the call to `dj_database_url` completely overriding your existing default database configuration.

The two ways to fix this are either to put a guard around that call:

```
if os.environ['DATABASE_URL']: 
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

or, better, remove the DATABASES dictionary declaration altogether and use the default parameter to that library:

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://joe:####@localhost/texchange')}
```

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies. I've been all over the place with this problem so I forgot that detail. What is the #### in the default value supposed to represent? EDIT: Nevermind, that is the default if I don't declare DATABASES at all. I understand.